# log4j Properties file on daily basis

Tags: java, log4j, rollingfileappender

I have a log4j properties file and i want to generate log file on daily basis and remove the file before today i mean it should contains only today's log file.

I have used following Properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,Appender2
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=log/AlertLogfile.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.append=true
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Comment: I am getting following Error:  ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.

Comment: This  Error is occuring when making the  connection with Elastic Search using TransportClient in Java and using the TransportClient 5.5.1 .

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of [`DailyRollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html)

The rolling schedule is specified by the `DatePattern` option. This pattern should follow the `SimpleDateFormat` conventions. In particular, you must escape literal text within a pair of single quotes. A formatted version of the date pattern is used as the suffix for the rolled file name.

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,Appender2
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=log/AlertLogfile.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.append=true
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```